# vgg16 model not converging

Tags: keras, deep-learning, computer-vision, classification

I tried to train keras's VGG16 on my dataset of orca calls with 8 classes. Data contains 7 classes for orca calls and 1 class for negative. Data contains spectrogram of orca calls and their corresponding labels.

Even after 50 epocs of training, loss and accuracy is not changing at all. I have tried feature scaling and various learning rate but model is not learning anything at all. I have checked the data manually, it is fine.

code:

```
model = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(include_top=True, weights=None, input_tensor=None, input_shape=(320, 480, 3), pooling='max', classes=8)
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8, decay=1e-6, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=X_train, y= Y_train, batch_size=16, epochs=2000, shuffle=True,validation_split=0.2)
```

I have read some research papers and I have done some contrasting and other type of preprocessing on images according to those papers. Upper half of images is turned to white as the frequencies I am interested in lies in second half. I chose `cmap ='gray'`, as the frequencies popped out more in it. Should I go for some another cmap?

Some Images from my dataset:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Kaggle kernal: https://www.kaggle.com/sainimohit23/myorcanb.

Comment: how many records do you have?  VGG16 is a complex model (138 million params?), so if you don't have enough data, you may want a simpler model.

Comment: What do you mean by 'loss and accuracy is not changing at all' ? Do the fluctuate a little or remain constant? What have you tried to debug?

Comment: @kmhI have dataset of around 350 images. What kind of model should I use?

Comment: @Sharky After first epoch 'loss and accuracy' changed a bit and then  they are same for every epoch. As I'm using a model which keras provids. So, I have nothing much to debug. Only thing I can do is to work on data and hyperparameters.

I will attach some images for you to look.

Comment: 350 is way too small for such a complex model. Start with just a couple of layers, convolutional or fc's and see what results you can get. Then almost all you can do is  transfer learning. Take some pretrained model, and try to finetune weights to your data

Comment: I only have 18  audio samples of 1 sec. I generated 350 images using data argumentation. If I generate more data then it will get repetitive.

@Sharky I have one more doubt. Should I use Batch Normalization and dropout? As you said data is not big enough. So, I think adding those layers may make it even harder for model to train.

Comment: Primary purpose of adding regularization is to reduce overfitting which is not the case. Batchnorm can help, but model capacity is simply way too big for this data. Try batchnorm with a simple model and see how it affects training.